# How to get excel application ribbon is hide/show using interop C#

Tags: excel, windows, c#-4.0, office-interop

I'm creating windows application in c#, where automating MsOffice Excel.

I'm trying to get excel application ribbon is currently hide/show.

Following code:

```
public static bool EvaluateRibbonDisplay(IQuestion question, string filename, ShowHide display)
    {
        ExcelInterop.Application excelApplication = null;
        try
        {
            excelApplication = new ExcelInterop.Application() { Visible = false, DisplayAlerts = false, ScreenUpdating = false };
            ExcelInterop.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(filename);

            bool result = false;
            var abc = excelApplication.ExecuteExcel4Macro("Get.ToolBar(7,\"Ribbon\")"); \\always returing true
            var abcd = excelApplication.CommandBars["Get.ToolBar(7,\"Ribbon\")"].Enabled;\\always returing true
            if (excelApplication.ExecuteExcel4Macro("Get.ToolBar(7,\"Ribbon\")") == Convert.ToBoolean(EnumStringExtension.GetDescription(display)))
                result = true;

            excelWorkbook.Close();

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            QuitApplication(excelApplication);
        }
    }
```

to hide/show the ribbon, i use Ctrl+F1. But the above code is returning always true.

can anyone please help me, how can i get the ribbon status.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For me the Height of the first control in the ribbon changes when it's hidden. Visible = 145, Hidden = 57. Hopefully you can do something with this observation

```
Sub RibbonExample()

    Dim cbar As CommandBar

    For Each cbar In Application.CommandBars
        If cbar.Name = "Ribbon" Then
            Debug.Print cbar.Controls(1).Height & "x" & cbar.Controls(1).Width
        End If
    Next cbar

End Sub
```